# refresh cells in custom tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView and  a detailView where the user can change the data. It worked perfectly until I programmatically changed the cells from subtitle to custom. Now when I edit the data and I go back I see the new data overlapping the old one,this despite of the [self.tableView reloadData] in viewDidLoad.The data change is working well because if I relaunch the app the new data is displayed.

Also the separator lines between the cells are not covering the whole width.

Just to be sure here is the code for the custom cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UILabel *mainLabel, *detailLabel, *secondLabel;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (!cell)
{
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

mainLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 5.0, 220.0, 15.0)];
// mainLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
mainLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
mainLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
mainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
mainLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];

secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.0, 5.0, 200, 15.0)];
// secondLabel.tag = MAINLABEL_TAG;
secondLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
secondLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
secondLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
secondLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

detailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 20.0, 220.0, 25.0)];
// detailLabel.tag = SECONDLABEL_TAG;
detailLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
detailLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
detailLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];


SNMGps *aCell = [arrayOfCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
mainLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aCell.name];
secondLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",aCell.gpsID];
detailLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",aCell.notes];
return cell;
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain better, Do you see the the native labels too? as for the separator, are you building on iOS 7?

Comment: The `reloadData` in the `viewDidLoad` will not be useful, try to put it in the `viewWillAppear` as Virus said.

Comment: @shannoga Yes, I see the old labels too and yes, I'm building in IOS7. The separator shows to short te whole time, not just when I edit a record.

Comment: @Zaphod I did that to, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Reload the whole section. I was having the same issues. This code worked perfectly for me, and it's only one line.

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

//don't forget to end refresh with 
[refreshControl endRefreshing];
```

As opposed to the multiple lines.

Why does it work? It reloads the entire section so however many cells you have in a section, this reloads them rather than trying to do a statement with a count or something fancy.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reload tableview in viewWillAppear.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thank You Viruss, I try that but the result is the same.

Comment: `reloadData` does *not* (necessarily) trigger redraws on views in table view cell...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just reloading the rows that are affected?

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure where should I put that, I tried in viewWillAppear, but it doesn't help.

Comment: I think the problem is not the reloadData or anything like that. The problem is that UITableViewCells are reused. When you display one, you add subviews. The cells will then have the subviews added, but when it creates another, the cell is resused and another set of subviews is added. This is when you get the text on top of each other. You solution is to create your own UITableViewCell Class and add subviews there and then only edit the text. check this link and look at the customize table view cell http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

It's very probably because of the reuse of the cells. When you reuse a cell, it's not a new one (that's why it is so fast, you don't destroy and recreate a cell).

So the only thing you need, in the `else` of your `if (!cell)` is to remove all labels in your cell, and thing will be alright!

For instance:

```
if (!cell) {
    ...
}
else {
    for (int i = cell.contentView.subviews.count -1; i>=0; i--) {
        UIView * v = [cell.contentView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            [v removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, I'm a beginner and I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Thank you for the example, now I understand better. I tried but the result is the same. What I don't understand is that the very same method was working perfectly in a standard view style, would it be better if I would configure the cell with the storyboard?

Comment: My mistake! I've edited the example, it removed the labels from the `cell` instead of the `cell.contentView`! Try it, and that should work! Let me know...